# Does (A∩C)=(B∩C)∧(A∪C)=(B∪C) mean {(A∩C)=(B∩C)}∧{(A∪C)=(B∪C)} ?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I don't know about set operator's priority exactly.
I think '=' operator is prior to '^'.
Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

The $\land$ symbol goes between *claims* and produces a new *claim*.

The $=$ symbol goes between *things* and produces a *claim*. (Here the "things" appear to be sets).

$B\cap C$ and $A\cup C$ are both *things* (i.e. sets), so the $\land$ symbol cannot connect them. The operand on each side of the $\land$ *has to* include the $=$ signs, because that's the only thing in the formula that produces *claims*.